# Is it possible to have multiple level generics in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to figure out if C# supports something like multi-level generics or how to do it correctly. Basically I want to do the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractPlugin<V, T> : IPlugin
where V : IPluginAccess
where T : IPluginProcessor<V>
```

Basically I want to 'use' one of the generic parameters inside the declared class, which is pretty much basics, but the other parameter I want to use on a subtype.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What did the compiler say when you tried it? ;-)

Comment: It seems to compile fine.

Comment: @Magnus Then it will work :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, the below classes and interfaces are for demonstrating this. They can vary in *multiple* ways.

```
public interface IPluginAccess { }
public class PluginAccess : IPluginAccess { }

public interface IPluginProcessor<T>{}
public class PluginProcessor :  IPluginProcessor<PluginAccess> { }

public interface IPlugin { }
public abstract class AbstractPlugin<V, T> : IPlugin
    where V : IPluginAccess
    where T : IPluginProcessor<V>
{ }
public class BasicPlugin : AbstractPlugin<PluginAccess,PluginProcessor> { }
```

And you can make use of it like this.

```
AbstractPlugin<PluginAccess, PluginProcessor> abstractPlugin = new BasicPlugin();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like `AbstractPlugin<int>` where this is resolved to `AbstractPlugin<IPluginProcessor<int>>` i have to disappoint you. You have really to write `AbstractPlugin<IPluginProcessor<int>,int>` in order to use your code. I have similar code where I have to do the same.